# Is there a name and notation for this modified permutation sequence?

Tags: permutations

I just into this sequence for a problem I'm working on and wondered if it had a name and a mathematical notation. It's the result of creating permutations with replacement where there's also a null case but they can't all be null. There's also no distinction between choosing "null" and then an object and the reverse order.  Here's an example if you're selecting from two objects:

```
object1
object1-object1
object1-object2
object2
object2-object1
object2-object2
```

So for two objects there are six possible cases. I was curious what the number of cases there would be for each number of objects and it looks like it is:

```
1 = 1
2 + 2*2 = 6
3 + 3*3 + 3*3*3 = 39
4 + 4*4 + 4*4*4 + 4*4*4*4 = 340
```

Is there a mathematical symbol for this calculation? Does this sequence have a name?

Comment: $n+n^2+n^3+\cdots+n^n$ is a geometric sequence with 1st term $n$, $n$ terms, and common ratio $n$. See also http://oeis.org/A031972

Comment: Is that OK, jss?

Comment: Yea, sounds like there's no official name or single-symbol notation but you gave me the best way to describe it and the website provides a nice formula: a(n) = (n^(n+1)-1)/(n-1) - 1

Feel free to add this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n+n^2+n^3+\cdots+n^n$ is a geometric progression with first term $n$, $n$ terms, and common ratio $n$. By the formula for the sum of a geometric progression, we have $$n+n^2+n^3+\cdots+n^n={n(n^n-1)\over n-1}$$ The sequence is tabulated, with more information, at the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/A031972).